# find all kinds but get one for every kind in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I create MessageScheme to save a message between two users, one document for one message. Now I want to find a list of people who have chated with specific person, what should I do?

I did this way, but it is not efficiency:

```
Message.find({$or: [{receiverId: specificId}, {senderId: specificId}] 
                }).sort('-created').limit(100).exec(function (err, results) {
                res.jsonp(results) //the results will content all documents have specificId
    })
```

This is the model in mongodb

```
 var MessageSchema = new Schema({
        created: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        content: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            trim: true
        },
        senderId: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
        receiverId:{
            type: String,
            default: '',
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why it is not efficient? Just put indexes on both fields and it will fly.

Comment: @Salvador Dali Not efficient, example: user A sent and receive 100 messages total with user B and user C. So to get the list of people user A have chated with, we just want to find 2 documents which have user B and user C, but the way I do will find all 100 documents

Comment: Then create a `chats` collection that tracks who chatted w/ whom. That collection could also contain a `last_message_date` or `message_count` field. Update that collection in-place or using a worker that scans the message collection from time to time.